# Ошибка конструктора Wpf application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image: Ошибка при создании wpf app]
Доброго времени суток. При создании `Wpf` проекта конструктор выдаёт ошибку, в которой говорится, что:

```
"System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1"

Exception details:

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.AssemblyHelper.get_InstallationPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.AssemblyHelper.get_XamlDesignerTestBinariesPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.TestAssemblyResolver.ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.AssemblyService.ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName, IEnumerable`1 assemblyResolverTable)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.AssemblyService.ResolveAssembly(String assemblyPath, String assemblyFullName, String projectPath, ReferenceAssemblyContext context, Boolean useReflectionOnlyLoad)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.GetAssemblyInformationInternal(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.UpdateTargetAssembly()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyService.GetProjectAssemblyResolver(IHostProject project)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Metadata.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyService.CreatePlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver(IHostProject project)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.Project.ProjectContextManager.CreatePlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver(IHostProject project)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

Comment: Ну проект-то компилируется и запускается?

Comment: Да, проект запускается с рабочим дизайнером на других компьютерах.

Comment: То есть проблема только в дизайнере, или программа не запускается?

Comment: Проблема в дизайнере.

Comment: Поди параметр добавили в конструктор окна

Comment: Попробуй в настройках проекта посмотреть может там гденибудь какойнибудь путь затерлось в ""

Comment: Провел ряд проверок - отклонения не выявил.

Comment: "at System.IO." - System.IO входит в .Net - переустановил framework - проблема не разрешилась

Comment: Настройки студии сбросьте

Comment: (1) Сделайте полный Rebuild проекта. (2) Если не поможет, забейте.

Comment: Проблема решена путем переустановки более новой версии .NET - искренне благодарю всех за помощь :)